# How to Use Powershell Module in an ADO Pipeline?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell .psm1 module that contains many functions I'd like to use in many Azure Devops yaml **build** pipelines, and maybe later in **release** pipelines as well.  I want to publish the module as an ADO Artiact in a feed and use it in many places.

GOAL: I **think** my goal here is to use the commands `Register-PSRepository` and then `Install-Module` to make the module's contents from a feed as a PSRepository available to later steps or tasks in the pipeline.  I was using this [Microsoft Learn Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops) as a guide for all the steps that work (below) but trying to adapt the final step to run in an Azure ADO pipeline.

PROBLEM: Pipeline fails to register the package as a PSRepository.

WHAT WORKS:

1. All functions are defined and tested locally in the Axis.DevOpsLib.psm1 file
2. All functions are made visible with Export-ModuleMember -Function
3. I created a manifest using `nuget spec Axis.DevOpsLib` -- this works
4. I edited the .psd1 file as necessary
5. I created a nuspec file using `nuget pack .\Axis.DevOpsLib.nuspec` -- this works, nupkg file created
6. I published the package to a ADO private feed which is used by many of our other pipelines using `nuget push Axis.DevOpsLib.1.0.0.nupkg -ApiKey AzureDevops -Source "Axis-Private"` -- this works, the nuget package of the correct versio shows up in the feed as expected. So far, so good.

(in code below, I realize that once this works I will need to grab username and token from the Key Vault, keeping it simple until concept is proved)

WHAT IS FAILING:

```
variables:
  system.debug: true
  feed: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/_packaging/Axis-Private/nuget/v2
  cred: '{"endpointCredentials": [{"endpoint":"$(feed)", "username":"<username>", "<patcleartext>":"ACCESS TOKEN"}]}'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'register'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '<subscriptionid>'
      ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
      Inline: 'Register-PSRepository -Name Axis.DevOpsLib -SourceLocation "$(feed)" -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential "$(cred)" -Verbose'
```

RESULTS:

`-Verbose` mode of course gives a lot of output.  The first sign of real trouble in the build log in the `register` task:

```
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=TaskHub;feature=AzurePowerShellV5]{"moduleSource":null,"targetAzurePs":"null"}
Validate-VersionParameters: Cannot convert value 'null' to type 'System.Version'.
VERBOSE: The value of the module path is: /usr/share/az_null
VERBOSE: No module path found with this name
VERBOSE: The updated value of the PSModulePath is: /home/vsts/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/opt/microsoft/powershell/7/Modules
Exception: /home/vsts/work/_tasks/AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62/5.220.0/Utility.ps1:94
Line |
  94 |  …             throw ("Could not find the module path with given version …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Could not find the module path with given version.
```

I really don't know what to make of this, not sure where to look to correct whatever is null with VersionParameters, the weirdly null module path, or even if my approach is correct or complete.  Can anyone advise on how to find address this error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the nuget and tried to import it yourself locally? Just because it was built and uploaded does not necessarily mean the content is actually valid.

For me the error message does not seem to come from the code-block you provided but probably later when you try to load a specific version?

---

You could also use the build account to auth to nuget and load the module, instead of having a separate service account or user credentials. For this to work you will need to auth the build account on the nuget feed.

```
parameters:
  - name: ModuleName
    default: Module
  - name: nugetFeed
    default: nugetFeedName
  - name: nugetProject
    default: project
  - name: organization
    default: organization

steps:
  - powershell: |
      $patToken = "$(System.AccessToken)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
      $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$(System.AccessToken)", $patToken) 
      try {
        Register-PackageSource -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name ${{ parameters.nugetFeed }} -Location "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/${{ parameters.organization }}/${{ parameters.nugetProject }}/_packaging/${{ parameters.nugetFeed }}/nuget/v2" -Credential $credential
        Install-Module -Name ${{ parameters.ModuleName }} -Credential $credential -AllowClobber -Force -Verbose
        Write-Output "Force importing module"
        Import-Module ${{ parameters.ModuleName }} -Force -Verbose
      } catch {
        throw $_
      }
    displayName: Import modules
    name: importmodules
```

This works for me because I always want to use the latest version.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're suggesting I use a local PowerShell session to try to load the nuget?  As to your build account idea, that's actually closer to what the "real" pipeline does already, does a NugetAuthenticate before building components which rely on other nuget packages.  So I might try your solution to see how that works.    I was following the Microsoft Learn tutorial, which uses a PAT, but "in real life" that's not how our mature pipelines work.  Let me give this a try, thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work for a remote PS session in azure - this should also work.

If you want to try to use NugetAuthenticate, there's some mentions here how to do it.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13215